# Current position of Cursor

Tags: c#, winforms

the problem is that I try to get current position of picturebox. When I use MouseEvenArgs everything is ok. But when I try to detect position using

```
 Cursor.Position.X;
```

It doesn't work the right way. The difference is near 20-30px. It seems to me that it gives me a bit different positions.

So, the question: is there any difference between the  positions that were get byMouseEventArgs or Cursor.Position? And are there any other ways to detect my current cursor position without using Mouse Events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cursor.Position` measures screen coordinates. You can map between screen and client (the form) coordinates using [PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) and `PointToScreen` methods.

[MouseEventArgs.GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition.aspx) returns

> the position of the mouse pointer relative to the specified element.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229598.aspx) - Windows Forms Coordinates

Answer (score 0):

The default clipping rectangle of the Cursor is the whole screen and the coordinates you receive from MouseMove are translated to the current control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx